# Why did he take out the $i$ from this equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

If he wants the imaginary part then why did he remove the $i$ symbol from the last part?

[image: derivation]

Comment: The imaginary part of a complex number is a real number, for example the imaginary part of $2+3i$ is $3$. Is this your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imaginary part is the coefficient of $i$ in a complex number.  So by itself it's a real number.

If $z=x+iy$ is a complex number, then the imaginary part of $z$ is $y$, not $yi$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$(\frac {2-i}{5})(e^{2x}\cos x + ie^{2x}\sin x) $$ $$=\frac {e^{2x}}{5}(2\cos x - i\cos x + 2i\sin x + \sin x) $$

Take the imaginary part from this to get the answer. Note that the part attached to the $i $ is real.